# Label backround colour difference between 'bg' and 'background'

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a label widget and I want to change it's backround colour. Literally in all documentation about tkinter I found it says the 'bg' parameter allows you to change the background colour of the widget. Yet when I create a label such as:

```
my_label = Label(self, text="Some_Text", bg='red2')
```

I always get this error: unknown option "-bg". When I use 'backround' instead the configuring works. I have googled around and I saw others had this 'issue' as well. However it was not very clear to me why that happens. Is there something like 'bg' was accepted in an older version of ttk but it's not accepted in the newer versions? Or what is the reason for this? Please help me by explaining this to me. Thank you for reading!

Comment: Is that the `Label` from Tkinter itself, or the `Label` from ttk?  They have entirely different ways of configuring colors...

Comment: @jasonharper I have noticed if I use tk.Label after 'import Tkinter as tk' it works just fine. I was using the one from ttk indeed. I guess I have to read about the difference between the 2 as I do not know what it is :D. Thanks.